# Is it possible for a browser scroll event to be triggered by DOM manipulation (other than user actions or explicitly calling eg. $.ScrollTop)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am researching a problem where a user triggers a scroll event, we process it, and in the process of doing so are somehow triggering a second scroll event. Our code is similar to this. In real life, 'thead' is buried inside many levels of containers, etc.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    $('thead').css('position','fixed');
})
```

The triggering action **seems** to be fixing the position of an element. This causes document.height to change, which makes sense, but such actions do not normally cause a scroll event to occur (from what I can tell).

I can reproduce this in our app (which is a mountain of jQuery) with very specific combinations of browser height and document height (I can't see a pattern to it, though; I just know values that work).

I can't reproduce it in a simple case, and I've been trying to all day.

I am confident that $.ScrollTop() or equivalent functions are not being called, and that the user is only making a single gesture.

The jQuery event object looks to me like it is a second user initiated event, eg. there is nothing to suggest that event #2 was caused by event #1.

This is happening on Chrome, haven't tried other browsers. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make any element to be position:fixed/absolute, your document's height is changed because changed element become out-of-normal-flow and does not push next elements down (read CSS position property). It's the same as removing element from your page.

So, if you're at the bottom of the page and one of elements is gone, browser scrolls page up to compensate removed element's height (to leave you at the bottom of the page).